# Have ansible role retrieve its files from external location as part of its own role

Tags: ansible

So one thing we've encountered in our project is that we do not want to store our large files in our git repo for our ansible roles because it slows down cloning (and git limits files to 100 mb anyways).

What we've done is store our files in a separate internal location, where our files can sit statically and have no size restrictions. Our roles are written so that they first pull these static files to their local files folder and then continue like normal.

i.e.
roles/foo/tasks/main.yml

```
  - name: Create role's files directory
    file:
      path: "{{roles_files_directory}}"
      state: directory

  - name: Copy static foo to local
    get_url:
      url: "{{foo_static_gz}}"
      dest: "{{roles_files_directory}}/{{foo_gz}}"

  #....Do rest of the tasks...
```

roles/foo/vars/main.yml

```
roles_files_directory: "/some/path/roles/foo/files"
foo_static_gz: "https://internal.foo.tar.gz"
foo_gz: "foo.tar.gz"
```

The main thing I don't find really sound is the **hard coded path to the role's files directory**. I preferably would like to **dynamically look up the path** when running ansible, but I haven't been able to find documentation on that. The issue can arise because different users may check roles to a different root paths. Does anyone know how to dynamically know the role path, or have some other pattern that solves the overall problem?

Edit:

I discovered there's actually a {{playbook_dir}} variable that would return "/some/path", which might be dynamic enough in this case. Still isn't safe against the situation where the role name might change, but that's a way rarer occurrence and can be handled through version control.

Comment: The [docs for get_url](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/get_url_module.html) say that `dest` has to be an "absolute path".  I agree that allowing a relative path for local downloads would be nice to have.  Thanks for mentioning the `playbook_dir` variable:  that is the best solution I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

What about passing values from the command line?

```
---

- hosts: '{{ hosts }}'
  remote_user: '{{ user }}'

  tasks:
     - ...

  ansible-playbook release.yml --extra-vars "hosts=vipers user=starbuck"
```

http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line

Comment: Don't think this works because a playbook calls many roles, which can be abstracted from the user's knowledge. The role should entirely take care of itself without the user having to do extra work. This approach wouldn't scale

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add another possible solution: you can try to add custom "facter".

Here is a link to official documentation: http://docs.ansible.com/setup_module.html

And I found this article that might be useful: http://serverascode.com/2015/01/27/ansible-custom-facts.html